# How do I disable all exiting in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, system

I'm writing an examination piece of software for my workplace and would like to know how I can trap and cancel key-presses such as:

- ALT+F4
- WIN+TAB
- ALT+TAB
- WIN
- CTRL+ALT+DEL

I'm aware CTRL+ALT+DEL may not be possible, but if any of this is it'll be a step in the right direction!

Ideally I want to prevent the action, and then open a new form I've created saying 'Unauthorised keypress'

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-can-i-setup-a-computer-with-windows-7-to-be/89f3246f-baaf-45fc-b946-07450475a5b0

Comment: Also consider (http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/225922/How-do-I-Disable-AltplusF-Key-from-closing-my-app).

Answer (score 0):

as @SQLHound link relates... us the `FormClosing` event to handle what happens when a user attempts to close.  But if you want to block a boot attempt, then @Plutonix suggestion may help.  Something along these lines...

```
       Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

         Dim splashScreen as New Form
         splashScreen.OpenDialog
         e.Cancel=True

       End Sub
```